# Unable to Acknowledge Problems in Nagios when Using LDAP

Tags: ldap, nagios

I have LDAP authentication setup for my Nagios instance and it seems to be working properly such that that Nagios and Adagios recognize my username. Tonight I did notice that I'm unable to schedule downtime or acknowledge problems when logged in as myself. I verified that I'm a member of the same contact group that the default `nagiosadmin` was a part of previously and double checked the cgi.cfg file in which I made the following edits:

```
authorized_for_system_information=*
authorized_for_configuration_information=*
authorized_for_system_commands=*
authorized_for_all_services=*
authorized_for_all_hosts=*
authorized_for_all_service_commands=*
authorized_for_all_host_commands=*
```

Any thoughts on how I might be able to restore my ability to acknowledge alerts and schedule downtime?

Comment: "Unable" as in? Does the webinterface spit out an error message or does it fail silently? What does the Nagios log say?

Comment: My mistake, I didn't even think to include that. The web interface fails silently and the nagios.log file doesn't contain anything with regards to failures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reboot of the system resolved this issue. It seems that simply restarting the Nagios and httpd services wasn't enough to completely resolve everything.